# R: Combine duplicate rows and sequence date order

Tags: r, sorting, date, duplicates

First time posting after digging around trying to find an answer. My question relates to flattening duplicates and keeping data in date order.

In this project, participants came for follow-up assessments and recorded their weight over 20 weeks. As participants arrived on different days for the assessment, we have 20 columns of attendance number that contains the date of that attendance followed by 20 columns of their weight at that particular attendance. Somehow, participants have been duplicated and their measures are disjointed.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that each participant has a unique ID, so in the example below, p01 is one participant but an error in entry means they appear twice.

Additionally, by "flattening" I meant, is there a way that could merge these duplicate entries so each participant only has one observation/row. What was causing a bit of grief was figuring out how to order the weekly data and then also keep their recorded weight values

A simpler fictitious example shown below:

```
**What actually happened**
id  attendance_1  attendance_2   attendance_3  attendance 4  attendance 5    
p01  2018-05-01    2018-05-08     2018-05-15    NA            2018-05-28

     Weight_1   Weight_2  Weight_3  Weight_4  Weight_5
     179        176       178       NA        173

**What is recorded in dataset**
df
------
   id  attendance_1  attendance_2   attendance_3  attendance 4  attendance 5    
1 p01  2018-05-01    2018-05-08     2018-05-15    NA            NA
2 p01  2018-05-28    NA             NA            NA            NA

   Weight_1   Weight_2  Weight_3  Weight_4  Weight_5
1  179        176       178       NA        NA
2  173        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

So participant "p01" attended 4 out of 5 assessments, but their record has been duplicated and their "fifth" attendance is appearing as their "first" in their duplicate entry. Is there a way to "flatten" their record to correctly place their attendance dates and weight records in order?

In this example, I was thinking of creating an "end date" column based on 5 weeks from their start date using the `lubridate` package, but I don't know how to code moving values in their "correct" space, or if this is possible.

I have previously used this code in other analyses;

```
df_merged = aggregate(x = df, by = list(df$participants_ID), FUN = function(x) na.omit(x)[1])[,-1]
```

to flatten duplicate participants based on their ID, but this would overwrite the data in this case and wouldn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How would you know that attendance_1 in the second row actually corresponds to attendance_5 in the first row instead of attendance_4? From what I can tell there is nothing in your data that would indicate this.

Comment: Could you produce the data? Maybe like 20 lines would help create some code more than a couple of observations.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You structured your question well. I think there are two reason why so far nobody answered you. Firstly what do you mean by 'flatten'? At best give a fictional example of what you have and show precisely what you would like as a result (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291474/r-how-to-vapply-across-rows-for-xts-object/50291932#50291932). Secondly people tend to answer your question more often if you give them the code how you create the fictional data.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your comments. I haven't been well since posting so have only just got back into the office today, but thanks for all the comments on advice.

@SimonLarsen : So, each participant in the assessment is given a unique identifier (it also just happens in this pilot we have a small number of participants to keep track of IDs), and somehow during data entry they appear on two rows

Answer (score 1):

To deal with data cleaning problems of this type, you might look at the `tidyverse` packages especial `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

I've recreated several sample records based on your data and description and added a second patient to help check the solution.  With this record layout, the `appearance` data is put in key-value format and then the `weight` data. Using record numbers generated for record and patient ids, the two parts are joined together and NA rows omitted.

The code follows:

```
   library(tidyverse)
#
# assume that data for 2 patients would have following format
#

df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE,
             colClasses = c("character", rep("Date",5), rep("numeric",5)), 
text =  "id  attendance_1  attendance_2   attendance_3  attendance_4  attendance_5  Weight_1   Weight_2  Weight_3  Weight_4  Weight_5  
p01  2018-05-01    2018-05-08     2018-05-15    NA            NA           179        176       178       NA        NA
p02  2018-05-01    2018-05-08     2018-05-16  2018-05-22      NA           209        206       208      205        NA
p01  2018-05-28    NA             NA            NA            NA           173        NA        NA        NA        NA
p02  2018-05-28    NA             NA            NA            NA           203        NA        NA        NA        NA")

#
#  put attendance records in key-value format with record number and att_no
#
  df_att <- df %>%  select(id,attendance_1:attendance_5) %>% 
              gather(key = attendance, value = Date,  attendance_1:attendance_5) %>%
              mutate( rec_no = 1:n()) %>% 
              select(-attendance) %>% arrange(id, Date) %>% 
              group_by(id) %>% na.omit() %>% mutate(att_no = 1:n())
#
#  put weight records in key-value format with record number
#
  df_wt <- df %>%  select(id, Weight_1:Weight_5) %>% 
              gather(key = Weighing, value = weight, Weight_1:Weight_5) %>%
              mutate( rec_no = 1:n()) %>%
              select(-Weighing) %>% arrange(id, rec_no) %>% 
              group_by(id) %>% na.omit() 
#
#  join attendance and weight records by id and rec_no
#
   df_tot <- left_join(df_att, df_wt, by = c("id", "rec_no")) %>% 
      arrange( id, Date)
#
#  use spread to transform back to original format forming column names from att_no
#
  df_att_spd <- df_tot %>% mutate(attendance = paste0("attendance_",att_no)) %>%
            select(id, Date,attendance) %>% 
            spread(key = attendance, value = Date)
  df_wt_spd <- df_tot %>% mutate(weighing = paste0("Weight_",att_no)) %>%
           select(id, weight, weighing ) %>%
           spread(key = weighing, value = weight)
 df_tot_spd <- left_join(df_att_spd, df_wt_spd, by = "id")
```

This gives the result:

```
   id    attendance_1 attendance_2 attendance_3 attendance_4 attendance_5 Weight_1 Weight_2 Weight_3 Weight_4 Weight_5
  <chr> <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>       <date>          <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
  p01   2018-05-01   2018-05-08   2018-05-15   2018-05-28   NA                179      176      178      173       NA
  p02   2018-05-01   2018-05-08   2018-05-16   2018-05-22   2018-05-28        209      206      208      205      203
```

Please clarify if I've not properly understood your data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the OP has not shown the expected result. Therefore, I will show three different approaches.

The *first one* will "flatten" the record *to correctly place the attendance dates and weight records in order* as requested by the OP.

The *second one* moves the values in the correct space according to a regular weekly sequence with 7 days intervals between attendances.

The *third one* is a variant which handles situations where there are deviations from the regular scheme, i.e., if there are 6 or 8 days difference between the attendances.

#### 1. Flatten the record without gaps

```
library(data.table)
# read data
df1 <- fread(
"id   attendance_1  attendance_2   attendance_3  attendance_4  attendance_5    Weight_1   Weight_2  Weight_3  Weight_4  Weight_5
p01  2018-05-01    2018-05-08     2018-05-15    NA            NA              179        176       178       NA        NA
p01  2018-05-28    NA             NA            NA            NA              173        NA        NA        NA        NA")

cols <- c("attendance", "Weight")
# reshape from wide to long format with 2 measure vars simultaneously
long <- melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = patterns(cols), value.name = cols, na.rm = TRUE)
# reshape to long format in order of attendance witout gaps
dcast(long[order(attendance)], id ~ rowid(id), value.var = cols)
```

> ```
>     id attendance_1 attendance_2 attendance_3 attendance_4 Weight_1 Weight_2 Weight_3 Weight_4
> 1: p01   2018-05-01   2018-05-08   2018-05-15   2018-05-28      179      176      178      173
> ```

Note that `melt()` and `dcast()` functions from the `data.table` package allow for reshaping of multiple measure/value columns simultaneously.

This is equivalent to [WaltS' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294900/3817004) but much shorter.

#### 2. Flatten the record according to weekly pattern

```
library(data.table)
# read data
df1 <- fread(
  "id   attendance_1  attendance_2   attendance_3  attendance_4  attendance_5    Weight_1   Weight_2  Weight_3  Weight_4  Weight_5
p01  2018-05-01    2018-05-08     2018-05-15    NA            NA              179        176       178       NA        NA
p01  2018-05-29    NA             NA            NA            NA              173        NA        NA        NA        NA")
```

Note that `2018-05-28` has been replaced by `2018-05-29` to fit in the weekly pattern.

```
cols <- c("attendance", "Weight")
# reshape from wide to long format with 2 measure vars simultaneously
long <- melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = patterns(cols), value.name = cols, na.rm = TRUE)
# coerce attendance from class character to class Date
long[, attendance := as.Date(attendance)]
# create date sequences for each id
date_seq <- long[, .(attendance = seq(min(attendance, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                      by = "week", length.out = 5L)), by = id]
# right join with date_seq to fill in gaps
long2 <- long[date_seq, on = .(id, attendance)]
```

If all ids share the same start date there is simplified way to reshape to wide format:

```
dcast(long2[order(attendance)], id ~ attendance)
```

> ```
>     id 2018-05-01 2018-05-08 2018-05-15 2018-05-22 2018-05-29
> 1: p01        179        176        178         NA        173
> ```

If the ids have separate start dates we need to have "neutral" column headers:

```
dcast(long2[order(attendance)], id ~ rowid(id), value.var = cols)
```

> ```
>     id attendance_1 attendance_2 attendance_3 attendance_4 attendance_5 Weight_1 Weight_2 Weight_3 Weight_4 Weight_5
> 1: p01   2018-05-01   2018-05-08   2018-05-15   2018-05-22   2018-05-29      179      176      178       NA      173
> ```

#### 3. Flatten with gaps and approximate dates

```
library(data.table)
# read data
df1 <- fread(
  "id   attendance_1  attendance_2   attendance_3  attendance_4  attendance_5    Weight_1   Weight_2  Weight_3  Weight_4  Weight_5
p01  2018-05-01    2018-05-08     2018-05-15    NA            NA              179        176       178       NA        NA
p01  2018-05-28    NA             NA            NA            NA              173        NA        NA        NA        NA")
```

Note that `2018-05-28` is used again which is 13 days apart from the previous attendance

```
cols <- c("attendance", "Weight")
# reshape from wide to long format with 2 measure vars simultaneously
long <- melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = patterns(cols), value.name = cols, na.rm = TRUE)
# coerce attendance from class character to class Date
long[, attendance := as.Date(attendance)]
# create date sequences for each id
date_seq <- long[, .(date = seq(min(attendance, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                      by = "week", length.out = 5L)), by = id]
# creat helper column for rolling join
long2 <- long[, date := attendance][
  # rolling join to nearest date
  date_seq, on = .(id, date), roll = "nearest"]
# set data of dates which are more than 1 day off of the regular weekly pattern to NA
long2[abs(attendance - date) > 1, (cols) := NA]
long2
```

> ```
>     id variable attendance Weight       date
> 1: p01        1 2018-05-01    179 2018-05-01
> 2: p01        2 2018-05-08    176 2018-05-08
> 3: p01        3 2018-05-15    178 2018-05-15
> 4: p01        1       <NA>     NA 2018-05-22
> 5: p01        1 2018-05-28    173 2018-05-29
> ```

```
# reshape to wide format
dcast(long2[order(date)], id ~ rowid(id), value.var = cols)
```

> ```
>     id attendance_1 attendance_2 attendance_3 attendance_4 attendance_5 Weight_1 Weight_2 Weight_3 Weight_4 Weight_5
> 1: p01   2018-05-01   2018-05-08   2018-05-15         <NA>   2018-05-28      179      176      178       NA      173
> ```